# multi-panel reframe not working as expected

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

I have the following reframe code:

```
;;sub
(reg-sub
 :active-panel
 (fn [db]
   (:active-panel db)))

;;event
(reg-event-db
 :active-panel
 (fn [db [_ new-panel]]

   (assoc db :active-panel new-panel)
   ))

(defn another []
  (fn []
    [:div

     [:p "another"]

     ]
    )
  )

(defn main []
  (fn []
    [:div
     [button {:label "Button"
              :on-click #(dispatch [:active-panel :another])
              }]
     ]
    ))

(defmulti panels identity)
(defmethod panels :main [] [main])
(defmethod panels :another [] [another])
(defmethod panels nil [] [:p "nil"])
(defn main-panel []
  (let [active-panel (subscribe [:active-panel])]
    (fn []
      (panels @active-panel))))
```

Basically, there's a button in the main (default) panel, which upon clicking should land to the :another panel, but instead it flickers between the "nil" panel and the :another panel. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your example code seems correct. When a Re-Frame app flickers, it's most of the time caused by unexpected dispatches. Have a look at these two examples:

```clj
;; Correct
[:button {:on-click #(js/alert "I got clicked")}
  "Click me"]

;; Incorrect
[:button {:on-click (js/alert "I got clicked")} ;; notice the missing `#`
  "Click me"]
```

If your javascript event handler is not a function, it will evaluate as soon as the component renders, triggering an effect. 
If it `dispatch` some event, you can create a loop making your app flicker when components render.

Since your example code seems correct to me, I would advise you to search for such mistakes in your source code.